# How does garage door opener detect car's trunk door is open?

Tags: sensor, parking

Today, I accidentally leave my Minivan's trunk door open inside the garage.
When I press the garage door opener's close button, it detected the trunk door, and the operation was canceled.

I have sensor at the bottom of the garage door. So how does it detective the top of my garage door?

Comment: Obstructions can be detected several ways. Blocking an invisible beam across the floor of the garage door's safety circuit as well as an overload sensor of the motor drive unit may stop or reverse door closing.